# Vectors borrowing and ownership

Tags: rust

This doesn't work:

```
let vectors = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

for i in vectors {
    println!("Element is {}", i);
}

let largest = vectors[0];
```

Error message:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `vectors`
 --> src/main.rs:8:19
  |
2 |     let vectors = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  |         ------- move occurs because `vectors` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
3 | 
4 |     for i in vectors {
  |              -------
  |              |
  |              value moved here
  |              help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&vectors`
...
8 |     let largest = vectors[0];
  |                   ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

The vector has been moved into the loop. Its ownership — and that of its individual elements — has been transferred there permanently.

But this works:

```
let largest = vectors[0];
let largest2 = vectors[0];
```

I don't know why; the `vectors[0]` value should have been moved to `largest` and `largest2` should then fail, but it didn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `vectors` inside a `for..in` loop, Rust will call the [`IntoIterator::into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) trait method of the `Vec`, which takes ownership of `self`. Therefore you cannot use `vectors` afterwards.

```rust
use std::iter::IntoIterator;

// these are equivalent
for i in vectors { /* ... */ }
for i in IntoIterator::into_iter(vectors) { /* ... */ }
```

The [index operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html), on the other hands, calls the [`Index::index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html#tymethod.index) trait method of the `Vec`, which takes `self` by reference. Additionally, it automatically dereferences the value, so that if the items inside the vector implement `Copy`, they will be copied out of the vector instead of borrowed (you need to explicitly borrow if you want a reference):

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

// these are equivalent
let x = vectors[0];
let x = *Index::index(&vectors, 0);

// these are equivalent
let x = &vectors[0];
let x = Index::index(&vectors, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the values (probably `i32`) in your `Vec` implement the `Copy` trait, which means that they do not get moved out when indexing the vector, they get copied instead.

A `Vec` of such `Copy` types still doesn't implement `Copy` itself, so it gets moved into the loop. You can avoid this e.g. by writing

```
for i in vectors.iter() {
    println!("Element is {}", *i);
}
```

The dereference (`*`) gives you an owned value like you'd get in your original code sample. It isn't necessary for `println!`, but might be necessary for other uses.